# Alias for Remote Desktop (Windows 7 or 10)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop

My company is naming PCs using their asset tags.
This is fine if I'm only dealing with one PC, but I have to Remotely Connect to over 7 PCs (and laptops).

Is there a way I can use an alias with Remote Desktop?
For example, use "Lab_PC" instead of PC12345678.

*The company is in the process of upgrading PCs and Laptops to Windows 10, so we have windows7 PCs and Windows 10 PCs.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Given that you can connect to another computer by both their Hostname AND their IP Address, you can simply create an entry in your hosts file for each pc with their LAN IP Address.

You can then ping or RDP to that alias and connect on IP Address.

Keep in mind, this will work for as long as the IP Address doesn't change. When it does, you will have to update your hosts file.

That said, you may want to consider using something like Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection Manager, Devolution's Remote Desktop Manager Free, Royal TS, etc.. These programs basically allow you to setup RDP connections once, and then connect by simply double clicking them. Given that you have to do some setup anyway, this might be the preferred method anyway. Each connection opens in a tab so you can even connect to multiple pc's at the same time.

Comment: Do I modify the "hosts" file on my PC or on the remote one?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews On your PC